# How do I copy a certain value to its adjacent indexes in a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a Pandas dataframe, read in from an Excel file. One row in particular is giving me trouble. Expressed as a list, it is structured as follows:

```
lst = [0, 2022, 0, 0, 2023, 0, 0, 2024, 0] #and so forth
```

What I would like to do is take that list and get something back that looks like this:

```
lst = [2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2024, 2024] #and so on
```

I have tried the following:

```
for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
    if lst[i] > 0:
        lst[i - 1] = lst[i]
        lst[i + 1] = lst[i]
```

But that just returns a list comprised entirely of `2022`. How would you approach this problem?

Comment: This would be a GREAT time to learn how to use a debugger; once you see what this code is doing, it should be clear how to fix it.

Comment: Why are you expressing it as a list? Pandas rows are Series, not lists, and Pandas has tools specifically for cleaning data. Please provide a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take advantage of Pandas' tools specifically for cleaning data. We can [nullify](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) the numbers you don't want, then [forward-fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) one value and back-fill, e.g:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([lst])

df.where(df > 0).ffill(limit=1, axis=1).bfill(limit=1, axis=1).astype('int')
```

```
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
0  2022  2022  2022  2023  2023  2023  2024  2024  2024
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is `if lst[i] > 0:`. That will always be true after the first `2022` it encounters, because you do `lst[i + 1] = lst[i]`. When you then increment `i` and get to the next element, `2022` will be there and you'll keep doing the same thing until you reach the end of the list.

You need to skip one index each time a match occurs. You can't easily do this with a `for`, but you could use a `while`:

```py
i = 1

while i < len(lst) - 1:
    if lst[i] > 0:
        lst[i - 1] = lst[i]
        lst[i + 1] = lst[i]
        i += 1
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you manipulate the same list. You can create new one and update.

```
copied_lst = lst.copy()
for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
    if lst[i] > 0:
        copied_lst[i - 1] = lst[i]
        copied_lst[i + 1] = lst[i]
```